# VUE+LARAVEL+RESTfullAPI

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.7

Как правильно реализовать SPA приложениие? В связке VUE+LARAVEL.
Проблема в том что у меня есть Laravel/authAPI/JWT + axios/vue,для авторизации. 
И мне нужно создать защищенное API на Laravel.
Которое является устойчивым для вмешательства со стороны. Злобных хакеров. Правильно ли я понимаю что мне нужно будет передавать JWT токен перед обращение к API. И если я правильно это понимаю, то как мне это сделать.